# Import requirements from CSV file

Tags: enterprise-architect

During import requirements from csv file I have a message:

```
Bad object type when creating new record of type ''
```

File I was trying to import:

```
GUID$Name$Notes$Scope
{BF467CF6-FF97-4dd4-894C-3F09E713678C}$NameOfReq$description$Public
{71B26F9A-5418-499e-B635-F2DB158D3FF1}$Requirement1$$Public
{0}$Requir1$blah$Public
```

First 2 (+header) lines becomes from existing requirements and there is no problem with import.

Last line should create a new object of requirement in enterprise architect, but there is a message mentioned above.

Any solution? How should proper file to create (import from csv file) a new requirements look like?

Answer (score 6):

As "Type" you must enter "Requirement" ... nothing else! And ensure that your separator is a comma ... otherwise the import also will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for reviving this old thread, but I lately had the same problem and google found me this topic. I would have been happy about more infos though, which I will therefor add now.

**Solution:**

- Option 1: In your CSV, add a field "Type" with the value "requirement" for each entry
- Option 2: In EA in your import-export-specification leave the type-filter empty

**Reasons / understanding:**

In your Import/Export-Specification there is the field "Types", which represents a type-filter. So only entries in the CSV that have the specified type will be imported, all others will be ignored. The import log will show "Bad object type when creating new record of type 'FOOBAR'" for the ignored record. If there is no type-field specified in the import-export-specification, EA will show the empty type '' in the import log (instead of 'FOOBAR').

I guess the same goes for exports, but I didn't try that.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, including field "Type" in the CVS file does the job